# How does air passing through the secondary heat exchanger in an aircraft's AC pack get cooled if ram air is not available/insufficient?

Tags: air-conditioning

For example, if the aircraft is on ground and bleed air for the AC pack is provided by the APU.

Most explanations I've seen say that the air passing through the secondary heat exchanger in between the ACM's compressor and turbine stages is cooled by ram air, so I'm not sure how it would work in the scenario I mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's inside the packs? (Airbus a320)](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66841/whats-inside-the-packs-airbus-a320) From the accepted answer: "The impeller fan creates cooling air flow when airspeed is low."

Comment: Thank you, it does!